# Objective-C - Where is the leak here?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

Instruments shows me that I have a leak in the following code:

```
            CGContextMoveToPoint(c, startPoint.x, self.frame.size.height - offsetYBottom);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, endPoint.x, self.frame.size.height - offsetYBottom);
            CGContextClosePath(c);

            CGGradientRef myGradient;
            CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace;

            size_t num_locations = 2;
            CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
            CGFloat components[8] = { 0.0/255.0, 197.0/255.0, 254.0/255.0, 1.0f, 0.0/255.0, 197.0/255.0, 254.0/255.0, 0.25f };

            myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

            CGPoint myStartPoint, myEndPoint;
            myStartPoint.x = self.frame.size.width / 2;
            myStartPoint.y = 0.0;
            myEndPoint.x = self.frame.size.width / 2;
            myEndPoint.y = self.frame.size.height;

            CGContextSaveGState(c);
            CGContextClip(c);
            CGContextDrawLinearGradient (c, myGradient, myStartPoint, myEndPoint, 0);
            CGContextRestoreGState(c);
```

If I comment this portion, the leaks are gone.
startPoint and endPoint are CGPoint.

Responsible caller: CGTypeCreateInstanceWithAllocator.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), you have to release `myColorspace` and `myGradient` when you're done with them:

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);
CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
```

Comment: But why is that? Isn't the rule with alloc standing for this also?

Comment: If you "create" the colorspace or gradient it creates a c-object under the covers which is your responsibility to release.

Comment: You're dealing with CoreFoundation-style objects here, their memory management rules differ a bit from Cocoa and this is not Objective-C.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I wasn't referring to your comment (only saw it after posting).

Answer (score 1):

Try to release myGradient object

```
CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
```